# XML Output from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, output

I am trying to create an XML output from SQL that has 3 nested statements but have pretty minimal experience in this area. The code I've written is below:

```
select 
replace(replace(replace(
(
select ID as [@ID], 
(select cast(Name as int) as [@Name],
(select num as [@Number],
from #tbl_new_claims_export
for xml path('Num'),root('Numbers'), type
)
from #tbl_new_claims_export
for xml path('LineItem'), type
)
from #tbl_new_claims_export
for XML PATH('Line'),ROOT('Lines')
),'><','>'+char(10)+'<'),'<Num', char(9)+'<Num'), '<Num>', char(9)+'<Num>')  ;
```

I am trying to create an output that looks like this:

```
<Lines>
<Line ID ="1">

<LineItem Name ="Michael"/>

<Numbers>

<Num Number="24"</Num>

</Numbers>

</LineItem>

</Line>
```

For each Line, I want to see the Line, Name, and Number as shown above. However, it is showing multiple Names under each Line and then repeats the Number below. Can anybody help me troubleshoot this code?

Thanks.

Comment: It would really help if you can post the table structure and some sample data for your temp table. As posted it is incredibly hard to help much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without sample data with 1:n examples and the expected output it is reading in the magic glass bulb...

Anyway, this

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [Line/@ID]
   ,'Michael' AS [LineItem/@Name]
   ,24 AS [Numbers/Num/@Number]
FOR XML PATH('Lines')
```

will produce exactly the output you specify:

```
<Lines>
  <Line ID="1" />
  <LineItem Name="Michael" />
  <Numbers>
    <Num Number="24" />
  </Numbers>
</Lines>
```

If you need further help, please specify a minimal and reduced test scenario. Best would be a fiddle or some pasteable code like

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT, col1 VARCHAR(MAX)/*more columns*/);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES (1,'test1')/*more values*/
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info. This actually worked perfectly though, so thank you very much!